# How to view JavaFX aplets on Linux (Ubuntu 11.10) and Mac OS?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, javafx

**I would like to know if is it possible to view JavaFX aplets in Firefox / Chrome, under Linux (Ubuntu) and Mac OS?**

So far it works on Windows XP. I read the FAQ at http://javafx.com/faq/ and it mentions version 2.0 supporting only Windows at the moment 2011.

These are some JavaFx demos: http://jfx.wikia.com/wiki/Demos

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can download JavaFX for linux from here

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html

Preview release JavaFX 2.1 build b09